# Is there a function to stringify JSON with whitespace?

Tags: javascript, json, formatting

I am aware of the fact that for JSON whitespace matters. But, just for debug output, I would like to print JSON objects formatted, thus with tabs and newlines.

Is there a function in JavaScript for formatted JSON stringification?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The third argument of [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) controls spacing. So you can do this, for example :

```
var o = {
  a: {c:34}
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(o, null, '\t'));
```

This logs

```
{
    "a": {
        "c": 34
    }
}
```

This parameter can accept different kind of values :

> The space argument may be used to control spacing in the final string.
>   If it is a number, successive levels in the stringification will each
>   be indented by this many space characters (up to 10). If it is a
>   string, successive levels will indented by this string (or the first
>   ten characters of it).
>
> Using a tab character mimics standard pretty-print appearance: